# “Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;” error

Tags: windows-10, tortoise-svn

I'm trying to edit a log message in the `TortoiseSVN` repository on Windows 10. But while trying to commit a new message text the following message is appearing:

[image]

After some researching I found that it is necessary to modify the `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` file located in the `hooks` folder of the repository. This file contains bash script for Linux.

Therefore, I changed it content  for the Windows environment, like below:

```bsh
set REPOS="%1"
set REV="%2"
set USER="%3"
set PROPNAME="%4"
set ACTION="%5"

IF %ACTION% == "M" (IF %PROPNAME% == "svn:log" (EXIT 0))

echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited" >&2
exit 1
```

But I still get the same error message.

How I can adopt content of this file for the Windows environment to be able to edit log messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A hook script is a **program** triggered by some repository event, such as the creation of a new revision or the modification of an unversioned property.
>
> The hook can be a **batch file or an executable**.

In plain Engish - hook **must** be executed by OS even outside of SVN, repo etc (while have errors due to missing parameters or just useless - it have to have possibility to be running)

*.tmpl files can't be processed (in clean Windows). I see CMD-syntax in your snippet, thus - it has to be `pre-revprop-change.bat`

BTW, the shortest pre-revprop-change hook with the same functionality

```
rem Only allow log messages to be changed.
if "%4" == "svn:log" exit 0
echo Property '%4' cannot be changed >&2
exit 1
```